# CNContactViewController New Contact cancel button flashing

Tags: ios, cncontactviewcontroller

In iOS `CNContactViewController` -> `Add New Contact screen`, when user starts **typing text** in any field e.g (First Name, Last Name or Company etc) **cancel button is continuously flashing as soon text changes.**

I don't want flash/flick animation of cancel button.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> Actual Result : Cancel button flashing/flicking as text changes.
>
> Expected Result : Flashing/Flicking should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

It was an iOS issue. Please check with iOS 16 it will work fine.